# Select nodes of a mesh data with matlab to set boundary conditions

Tags: matlab, vector

I have imported a 2Dmesh file of a surface with the mesh data into matlab.

This mesh file has 3 columns: the first one with the node number, the second one with the x-coordinate of the node and the third one with the y-coordinate of the node.

I want to select the nodes inside this circle x²+y² = 4. After importing the data file into matlab I have three column vectors, the node vector, the x-coordinate vector and the y-coordinate vector.

Any tips to impose the x² + y² < 4 condition to do this? Thank you.

Comment: The circle is x²+y² = 4. Inside this circle there are nodes that want to know its node number in order to set a displacement in these nodes. The nodes inside this circle may be about 100, so I would like to obtain a column vector with the number of this nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with a for loop that scans the three vectors in parallel.

First of all, you might want to check that these 3 vectors have the same length. Let's say `x` is the vector with the x-coordinates, `y` is the vector with the y-coordinates and `idx` is the vector with the node numbers.

```
if(length(x)~=length(y) || length(x)~=length(idx) || length(y)~=length(idx))
   error('Vectors must have the same length.');
end
```

Then you can proceed.

```
SelectedNodes=[];
for i=1:length(x) %or length(y) or length(idx)...they must have the same length
    if(x(i)^2+y(i)^2<4)
        SelectedNodes=[SelectedNodes idx(i)];
    end
end
```

Now in `SelectedNodes` you have the IDs of the nodes that lie inside your circle, to know how many nodes lie inside your circle, simply evaluate its length (`length(SelectedNodes)`).

**Update**: As @rayryeng correctly pointed out, there is a much smarter way of doing this by using logical indexing instead of a for-loop. The logical indexing (in poor words) puts a logical `1` (true) in `i`-th position if the `i`-th element of a vector (or matrix) satisfies a particular condition. Otherwise there will be a logical `0` (false). By running, as suggested,

```
SelectedNodes=idx(x.^2+y.^2<4)
```

the code `x.^2+y.^2<4` will return an array of the same length as `x` (and `y`) containing `1`s or `0`s in position `i` depending on whether such element in `x` and `y` satisfies the circle equation. Such array will be the input of `idx` and that means "select from `idx` the value marked as `true`". Finally, this will be the result stored in `SelectedNodes`.

Comment: Would `SelectedNodes = idx(x.^2 + y.^2 < 4)` be more efficient?  The code you wrote can be made more efficient by using `logical` indexing.  `for` loops are not needed here.

Comment: Sure thing. But with a `for` loop you actually see step-by-step what's going on. On a second step you can as well optimize your code by avoiding loops and such.

Comment: Sure, I can see why you'd want to use a `for` loop, but I would think if one were to become a serious MATLAB user, you'd want to adopt good practices.  Also, consider using `numel` instead of `length`... that's just my personal preference though.